# linq query from one to many to many not letting me retrieve last many

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq

I have a jobmain table which has a single jobnumber for every job, then a jobparts table which has many jobparts for each job, then a jobpartsforms which has many forms for every job part.  Linq only allows the following:

```
Dim query = From jst In db.JobMains _
Where jst.JobNum = CInt(Session("JobNumber")) _
Select jst.JobParts
```

but I want to get the jobpartsforms which should look like this:

```
Dim query = From jst In db.JobMains _
Where jst.JobNum = CInt(Session("JobNumber")) _
Select jst.JobParts.JobPartsForms
```

How can I do this and why doesn't it work the way I think it should since the relationships are all built in already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flatten the query before selecting the JobPartsForms.

```
Dim query = From jst In db.JobMains _
Where jst.JobNum = CInt(Session("JobNumber")) _
From part in jst.JobParts _
Select part.JobPartsForms
```

Or with lambda syntax you can use SelectMany:

```
db.JobMains _
.Where(Funtion(j) j.JobNum = CInt(Session("JobNumber")) _
.SelectMany(Funtion(j) j.JobParts) _
.Select(Function(jp) jp.Forms)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with SelectMany? I couldn't figure out the syntax.

Comment: @nlehman I'm not particularly good with VB.NET but I've updated my answer with an example that should work